# Can I debug ActiveDirectory with Visual Studio Code PowerShell extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, powershell-5.0, vscode-debugger, powershell-core

It looks like the Visual Studio Code PowerShell extension is only able to debug scripts running on PowerShell Core.

Is it possible to debug PowerShell scripts when running PowerShell 5.1? I need to debug scripts accessing Active Directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, yes.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/powershell#_multiversion-support

TL;DR: Just click the version number in the lower-right corner.

[image]